# using string contains equal and double quote symbol in python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I want to comparison string with another but it contains = and " symbols .

String example :

```
"aria-live="polite">Showing"
```

In C++ i can put slash \ before the symbol like :

```
"aria-live\=\"polite\">Showing"
```

Another thing what if i want to initialize string with it like :

```
text = "aria-live="polite">Showing"
```

In python what can i do ?!